# Why can't I use that kind of ID as context with Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I try to scrape some links from Yahoo Finance, using node.js and cheerio. But I can't make it work with Yahoo ID's as context.

Here's the code I try to use:

```
 var request = require('request'),
     cheerio = require('cheerio');
     urls = [];

 request('http://finance.yahoo.com', function(err, resp, body) {
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
       var $ = cheerio.load(body);
       $('a', '#yui_3_16_0_1_1414729926453_1539').each(function() {
         var url = $(this).attr('href');
         urls.push(url);
       });
       console.log(urls);
    }
});
```

Maybe someone could help with a hint where I'm getting things wrong?

Comment: well are you sure this ID is still in http://finance.yahoo.com in the first place. I don't see it. Those IDs probably change a lot so you have to find another handle for your scraping

Comment: Yes, it was "live picking" ID's :)

Comment: Selector is long gone, so voting to close as not reproducible. Is there a reason not to use `#the_id a` though?